# Use gamer's avatar in Xbox game

Tags: xbox-live, avatars

I have been reading a lot about Xbox game development. Back in 2010-12, XNA technology was available so that a game could use the gamer's avatar.

When developing a game today, how can I use a gamer's avatar in the game ? I am aware that gamertag etc.. are available through Xbox live and creators or ID@xbox programs. I am also aware that I can use Unity/C#/Nuget and VS2017 to create a Xbox One and/or windows 10 game.

I am yet to find developer information related to avatars: what are the characteristics of the avatar ? how can I create one myself (coding) ? how to fetch avatar ? how to render it ? how to interact with it ? if at all possible...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether you are an XDA or UWP title.
In either case, you need to use the Xbox Live Services SDK (separate ones for XDA / UWP).  In there, there are API's for authentication and interrogating Gamer Services

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/

Comment: Thx for your reply. I read the docs regarding XNA dev for Xbox 360 and the gamers service, but this is very old. Looks like there is no avatar support for Xbox One ?

Comment: That is correct, MS deprecated the old Avatar API with XNA.  Most you can do in the Live services is retrieve avatar pics.
I do hope they bring them back one day.

Answer (score 0):

Avatars were supported for 360 games in the past, but that program has been gone for a while now. At this time there is no support for using your avatar in an Xbox game.

Comment: Thx. Any idea if this feature will eventually come back? Wouldn't it be nice for a gamer to upload a new virtual player in any compatible game, the avatar being based on a predefined topology?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. But feel free to add this suggestion to our Xbox User Voice forums: https://xbox.uservoice.com/forums/363186--new-ideas